# How to return an int variable from controller to view in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have created a global variable in my CartController for the quantity of an item, here is the declaration:

```php
class CartController extends Controller
{
    // defining global quantity variable
    private $quantity = 1;
```

Then in my `index()` function on the same controller, where I return the view, I pass through the `quantity` variable like so:

```php
public function index()
{
    $this->quantity;
    return view('cart.cart', ['quantity' => $this]);
}
```

But when I call it in the `cart.blade.php` file like this:

```html
<div class="display-quantity">
    {{-- Shows Quantity --}}
    <span class="item-quantity" id="item-quantity">{{ $quantity }}</span>
</div>
```

It gives me the following error:

```
TypeError
htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, App\Http\Controllers\CartController given (View: /Users/rosscurrie/mobile-mastery-latest/resources/views/cart/cart.blade.php)
```

[image]

I think I need to convert it to a string but I need to work with it as an integer so how do I get around this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It look like you're passing in `$this` as the `quantity`.

Try changing your controller's `index()` code to something like:

```
public function index()
{
    $myQuantity = $this->quantity;
    return view('cart.cart', ['quantity' => $myQuantity]);
}
```

It looks like the confusion here is with the `->` operator which in php is used to call on object's method or access an object's property the same way `.` works in Javascript. This statement `$this->quantity;` accesses the `quantity` property of `$this`, so to use it - you need to assign it to a variable (or use it directly). This would have also worked:

```
public function index()
{
    return view('cart.cart', ['quantity' => $this->quantity]);
}
```

You can always do things like `dd($this->quantity);` to ensure you are working with the correct information.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, that worked! If you are able to, could you explain why this works?

Comment: @RossCurrie I added more detail to my answer to hopefully clear it up